# Geolocation works on localhost, not on server online address

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, geolocation

I am a newbie in web programming and seeking for a help.
I have tested with a nodejs server the following geo-location solution:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

The following error is that this works ok on 127.0.0.1, but doesn't work on online / local server , like using XAMP and accessing it wit a local VM on bridged ip.

What should i do, or what have i missed.

Thx and sorry if i have made a mistake in explaining things

Comment: I think this is the cause: From the source page: "Note: As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure contexts such as HTTPS. If your site is hosted on an non-secure origin (such as HTTP) the requests to get the users location will no longer function."

Comment: but why does it work on 127.0.0.1 which is http?

Comment: "*[Locally delivered files such as http://localhost ... are considered to have been delivered securely.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts)*"